name property is not being recognized (Typescript + ReactNative)
My Icon component is receiving a name property that can be "up", "down", or "total" to use this string to generate the icon that will be displayed. It turns out that Typescript keeps pointing out an error in this name property, although it does not prevent the application from working. I tried to adjust in several ways but I am unable to remove this error.
My Index.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import {
    Container,
    Header,
    UserWrapper,
    UserInfo,
    Photo,
    User,
    UserGreeting,
    UserName,
    Icon,
    HighlightCards
} from './styles';
import { HighlightCard } from '@/src/components/HighlightCard';

export function Dashboard(){
    return(
        <Container>

            <Header>

                <UserWrapper>

                    <UserInfo>
                        <Photo source={{ uri: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/105324740?v=4' }}/>

                        <User>
                            <UserGreeting>Olá,</UserGreeting>
                            <UserName>Rodrigo</UserName>
                        </User>

                    </UserInfo>
                
                    <Icon name="power" />
                 </UserWrapper>

            </Header>

            <HighlightCards>
                <HighlightCard 
                    type="up"
                    title="Entradas" 
                    amount="R$ 17.400,00" 
                    lastTransaction="Última entrada dia 13 de abril"
                />
                <HighlightCard 
                    type="down"
                    title="Saídas" 
                    amount="R$ 1.259,00" 
                    lastTransaction="Última entrada dia 03 de abril"
                />
                <HighlightCard
                    type="total"
                    title="Total" 
                    amount="R$ 16.141,00" 
                    lastTransaction="01 à 16 de abril"
                />
            </HighlightCards>

        </Container>
    )
}


My HighlightCard.tsx (the error is here):
import React from "react";

import {
    Container,
    Header,
    Title,
    Icon,
    Footer,
    Amount,
    LastTransaction
} from "./style";

interface Props {
    type: 'up' | 'down' | 'total';
    title: string;
    amount: string;
    lastTransaction: string;
}

const icon = {
    up: 'arrow-up-circle',
    down: 'arrow-down-circle',
    total: 'dollar-sign'
}

export function HighlightCard({type, title, amount, lastTransaction}: Props){
    return(
        <Container type={type}>
            <Header>
                <Title type={type}>{title}</Title>
                <Icon name={icon[type]} type={type}/>
            </Header>

            <Footer>
                <Amount type={type}>{amount}</Amount>
                <LastTransaction type={type}>{lastTransaction}</LastTransaction>
            </Footer>
        </Container>
    )
}


The error is in the "name" property of the "Icon" component and says the following:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: PolymorphicComponentProps<"native", Substitute<IconProps<"arrow-up-circle" | "arrow-down-circle" | "dollar-sign" | "type" | "code" | "link" | "map" | "menu" | "video" | "circle" | "image" | "search" | "filter" | ... 272 more ... | "zoom-out"> & RefAttributes<...>, TypeProps>, void, void, {}, {}>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"arrow-up-circle" | "arrow-down-circle" | "dollar-sign" | "type" | "code" | "link" | "map" | "menu" | "video" | "circle" | "image" | "search" | "filter" | "key" | "download" | ... 270 more ... | "zoom-out"'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Substitute<IconProps<"arrow-up-circle" | "arrow-down-circle" | "dollar-sign" | "type" | "code" | "link" | "map" | "menu" | "video" | "circle" | "image" | "search" | "filter" | "key" | "download" | ... 270 more ... | "zoom-out"> & RefAttributes<...>, TypeProps>): ReactNode', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"arrow-up-circle" | "arrow-down-circle" | "dollar-sign" | "type" | "code" | "link" | "map" | "menu" | "video" | "circle" | "image" | "search" | "filter" | "key" | "download" | ... 270 more ... | "zoom-out"'.ts(2769)
createIconSet.d.ts(17, 5): The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FastOmit<Substitute<Substitute<IconProps<"arrow-up-circle" | "arrow-down-circle" | "dollar-sign" | "type" | "code" | "link" | "map" | "menu" | "video" | "circle" | ... 275 more ... | "zoom-out"> & RefAttributes<...>, TypeProps>, FastOmit<...>>, keyof ExecutionProps> & FastOmit<...> & { ...; }'
createIconSet.d.ts(17, 5): The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FastOmit<IconProps<"arrow-up-circle" | "arrow-down-circle" | "dollar-sign" | "type" | "code" | "link" | "map" | "menu" | "video" | "circle" | ... 275 more ... | "zoom-out"> & RefAttributes<...>, "type"> & TypeProps'
(property) name: "arrow-up-circle" | "arrow-down-circle" | "dollar-sign" | "type" | "code" | "link" | "map" | "menu" | "video" | "circle" | "image" | "search" | "filter" | "key" | "download" | ... 270 more ... | "zoom-out"
Name of the icon to show

See Icon Explorer app https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/

I tried typing in other ways and changing the logic but I couldn't make the error disappear

Just add as const at the end of your declaration of the icon variable const icon = {...} as const; Otherwise the compiler will infer the type as string (which is actually what you want most of the time, and why you have to opt-in to the narrower inference).
